# confusion with evaluation of the condition and the steps of a for loop

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, step-into

```
void draw_diamond(int n)
{
int mid_pos = ceil((double)n / 2);
int left_spaces = mid_pos-1;
int line_stars = 1;

putchar(10);
//printing from top through the middle of the diamond
for(line_stars, left_spaces ; line_stars <= n; line_stars+=2, left_spaces--);
{
    //printing the left_spaces
    for(int i=1; i<=left_spaces; i++)
        putchar(32);

    //printing the line_stars
    for(int i=1; i<=line_stars; i++)
        putchar('*');
    putchar(10);
}
```

...

I have problem here, when I `step into` the `for loop` for the first time, nothing happens, for the second one `for loop step is applied` e.g.: if I `pass 1 to n` then:

mid_pos =1;
left_spaces=0;
line_stars=1;

it goes inside the loop with:
left_spaces=-1;
line_stars=3;

the `for loop` prints 3 stars where it should print just 1.

I'm confused, I'd appreciate it if any one could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uh oh, watch out for the sneaky semicolon:

```
for(line_stars, left_spaces ; line_stars <= n; line_stars+=2, left_spaces--);
                                                                            ^
                                                                            |
```

This ends your `for` statement. The loop will just run until `line_stars` is greater than `n`. By the end, `line_stars` will now equal 3 (because it is increased by 2). `left_spaces` will be -1.

Now the rest of your code which is enclosed by curly brackets will execute. The first `for` loop won't run at all, but the second one will run from 1 until `line_stars` and, as we know, `line_stars` is 3, so we get 3 stars printed out.

Comment: Minor suggestion: `for(line_stars, left_spaces ;` - aside from taking up space on the line, this does absolutely nothing. use `for(;...` if you have nothing to initialize on the line.